# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3dd12f3a V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348}

Tags: android

A bit lost in the following Android app development error.

The error I'm getting in test Android phone is "Unfortunately,  has stopped"

And the log available is as follows (as available in LogCat in Android Studio):

```
2021-11-10 19:16:13.970 9937-9937/com.example.phprestsqlapp E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.phprestsqlapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3dd12f3a V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:364)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
        at com.example.phprestsqlapp.MainActivity$ServiceStubAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
        at com.example.phprestsqlapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.phprestsqlapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String apiPath = "https://<site.com>sample.php";
    private ProgressDialog processDialog;
    private JSONArray restulJsonArray;
    private int success = 0;

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_name_list);
        new ServiceStubAsyncTask(this, this).execute();
    }

    private class ServiceStubAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Context mContext;
        private Activity mActivity;
        String response = "";
        HashMap<String, String> postDataParams;

        public ServiceStubAsyncTask(Context context, Activity activity) {
            mContext = context;
            mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            processDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            processDialog.setMessage("Please  Wait ...");
            processDialog.setCancelable(false);
            processDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postDataParams.put("HTTP_ACCEPT", "application/json");

            HttpConnectionService service = new HttpConnectionService();
            response = service.sendRequest(apiPath, postDataParams);
            try {
                success = 1;
                JSONObject resultJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                restulJsonArray = resultJsonObject.getJSONArray("output");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                success = 0;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (processDialog.isShowing()) {
                processDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (success == 1) {
                if (null != restulJsonArray) {
                    ArrayAdapter listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.mobile_name_listview);

                    for (int i = 0; i < restulJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = restulJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            listViewAdapter.add(jsonObject.get("name"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                }
            }
        }


    }//end of async task
}
```

Any pointers to where and which file should I change to get this fixed please?

Any other code, log or details needed, pls let me know in comments and I'll furnish.

Comment: @markView - I see that you've answered a similar q at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526885/android-async-task-from-runnable-activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-origina. Any idea on this one please?

Answer (score 0):

this constructor is wrong

```
    public ServiceStubAsyncTask(Context context, Activity activity) {
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

you very shouldn't leave `Context`/`Activity` saved inside `AsyncTask`, that may cause memory leak (and you got one)

easiest way is to use `WeakReference`

```
    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;
    private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

    public ServiceStubAsyncTask(Context context, Activity activity) {
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
        mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }
```

and inside `onPostExecute` be prepared that `mContext.get()==null` or `mActivity.get()==null`, as `Activity`/`Context` may get killed/destroyed during this async operation

btw. `Activity` IS a `Context` instance, so keeping two separated variables is probably unnecessary, you may use then single argument constructor `new ServiceStubAsyncTask(this)` with only `mActivity` `WeakReference`

BUT note that [`AsyncTask` is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), there are plenty of better ways for doing background tasks (like linked in doc [coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines), simple `Thread`s, executors etc.)

Comment: Thanks @snachmsm. Its throwing error "app\app\src\main\java\com\example\phprestsqlapp\MainActivity.java:59: error: incompatible types: WeakReference<Context> cannot be converted to Context
            processDialog = new ProgressDial". Location is "        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            processDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);" function.  Will need some help as I'm new to app dev

Comment: thats because now `mContext` isn't a `Context`, its a `WeakReference<Context>`. you can get `Context` from it by calling `mContext.get()`, but before using it check if it isn't `null`